# updating a state in a reducer after put method

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to create a mern crud app, and now i'm trying to edit values of a project. I'm struggling with updating the current values of database into state.

When I dispatch the edit action, the `next state` in redux logger returns values 
before the editing, and I want it to return values of state with its edited values.

How do you return updated values to a state in a reducer?

This is my reducer

```
case projectActions.UPDATE_PROJECT:
{

    return {...state, 
           project:state.project.map(item=> 
           (item._id===action.payload._id) ? action.payload.data:item )
           , ?                       
           }        

}
```

to my understanding,

- `...state` is the state before updating
- `project:state.project.map(item=> (item._id===action.payload._id) ?
  action.payload.data:item)` is the updated value
- `?` this is the state with updated values.

I'm not sure how I return it? any input will appreciated

A picture of redux logger

the value is updated in the database but hasn't updated the props yet as you can see in the next state value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick rundown of spread props and object definitions;

`state` will be your previous state object.  `...state` means "extract all variables on this object".

So if `state` is `{test: 'foo', test2: 'bar'}`, then `...state` is `test: 'foo', test2: 'bar'`.  Note the missing object brackets.

This is useful when creating a new object based on pre-existing ones.  `{...state}` is applying all properties from `state` onto a new object.

`{...state, test2: 'foobar'}` will override the value of `test2` based on whichever value is furthest to the right.  So the resulting object will be `{test: 'foo', test2: 'foobar'}`.

This is what you're doing for the first 2 lines of your new state definition.  You are first applying the previos state properties with `...state`.  You are then overriding the previous value of `project` with the new value defined by

`state.project.map(item=> 
           (item._id===action.payload._id) ? action.payload.data:item )`

The final line of `, ?` is nonsense.  It should simply be removed.

If this isn't resulting in the new state you expect, I would attempt to log the value of the payload before your return.  A simple `console.log(action.payload)` should provide you with a good deal of information.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! that helped me understand redux state data manipulating. it seems the reducer is working fine. However, I did console log the action payload for update case and all i get is the edited value, then in the redux logger, in `next state` i'm having the values of state before editing. I'm not really sure whats the problem.

Comment: You code implies that the payload should be an object with an `_id` property, among (theoretically) some other updated attributes.  If you are getting a value, and not an object, from the payload response, then it's likely that your API is not returning the full information that your reducer is expecting.

Comment: I should clarify that i am getting an object which also includes data of the edited project on the action.payload console. I've added a picture of the redux logger to demonstrate.

Comment: You're not calling the `_id` value correctly;  `action.payload._id` should be `action.payload.data._id`.

Comment: That worked. I should pay attention to these things more. Thanks!